# Can objects in an OpenMP thread be modified from outside?

Tags: c++, openmp

I use OpenMP to parallelize calls like so:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
  for(std::size_t iter = 0; iter < visitors.size(); ++iter)
    {
      VisitorSPtr visitor_sp = visitors.at(iter);

      dataSetPtr->accept(*(visitor_sp.get());
    }
  // End of
  // #pragma omp parallel for
```

Each visitor is used in a different thread, thanks to the `#pragma omp parallel for` directive. Fine.

The `dataSetPtr->accept()` function that is called within the loop checks if the visitor has been cancelled by the user like this:

```
    if(visitor.shouldStop())
        break;
```

If that call returns true, the visit is not performed. That cancellation is trapped when a user clicks a button and a signal is emitted that is relayed to the visitor which sets a member boolean variable to state that cancellation has been requested. But the signal does not get to the visitor and the `if(visitor.shouldStop())` is of no use, that is, never evaluates to true even if the cancellation signal was properly emitted.

The connection is performed like this (`this` is the `MassDataIntegrator` object instance from which the connection is made, that receives the cancelling signal and that should relay it to the Visitor instance):

```
      connect(this,
            &MassDataIntegrator::cancelOperationSignal,
            visitor_sp.get(),
            &Visitor::cancelOperation,
            Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

My question: how can I modify objects that are in a `#pragma omp parallel for` loop from code that runs in another thread? I thought that would be trivial by using pointers. Evidently, I am missing some concept here. Could anybody help me sort this mis-understanding ? Thank you for your attention.

## SOLVED

The connect call above did not work for some reason (that I will investigate). So I tried using a lambda which, on the face, accesses directly the Visitor instance like this (I commented out the replaced code to show the difference):

```
  connect(this,
        &MassDataIntegrator::cancelOperationSignal,
        [visitor_sp](){visitor_sp->cancelOperation();});
          //visitor_sp.get(),
          //&TicChromTreeNodeCombinerVisitor::cancelOperation,
          //Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

We can consider this issue solved. How do I do that ?

Comment: Please note that with in the current form, I can only give a general answer to your question. If your issue persists and you need a specific answer, please create a [mcve] - ideally without QT.

Comment: Thank you, Zulan, for your answer. I have edited the question because I discovered after some digging that there was a programming error in it. However, I still do not know if it is possible to modify the state of an object (used in the parallel section) from outside of that section.

Comment: Ok, I have now solved this problem. I clearly had a problem with the Qt signal emitted as a response to the user wishing to cancel the computation: it did not get to the Visitor instance. I have added the solution to the initial post.

Comment: Even if it appears to be working as is, keep my answer in mind if you want it to be correct and portable.

Comment: Yes, Zulan, you are right. I need to think about this, although in the current implementation the cancelling can come from only one origin and affect each visitor apart. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you access a data location from multiple threads in OpenMP, and at least one of the accesses is a write access, you must protect **all read and write** accesses to this location with `atomic` directives (or other means to avoid race-conditions and ensure memory consistency).

Simply speaking, `shouldStop` should be implemented along the lines of:

```
bool r;
#pragma omp atomic read
r = this->cancelFlag_;
return r;
```

and `cancelOperation` like:

```
#pragma omp atomic write
this->cancelFlag_ = true;
```

This both ensures that there is no race condition in the unlikely case that a writing a `bool` needs two operations, and implies appropriate memory flushes to ensure that the result of the write is visible in other threads.